# How to set an HTTP proxy in Python 2.7?

Tags: python

I am trying to run a script that installs pip: get-pip.py and am getting a connection timeout due to my network being behind an HTTP proxy. Is there some way I could configure an HTTP proxy in my Python 2.7 installation to be able to install what I am trying to install?

Note: I am using Windows. Below is the error I am getting:

```
C:\SetupFiles>python get-pip.py
Downloading/unpacking pip
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pip
No distributions at all found for pip
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

It looks like `get-pip.py` has been updated to use the environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`.

Windows:

```
set http_proxy=http://proxy.myproxy.com
set https_proxy=https://proxy.myproxy.com
python get-pip.py
```

Linux/OS X:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy.myproxy.com
export https_proxy=https://proxy.myproxy.com
sudo -E python get-pip.py
```

However if this still doesn't work for you, you can always install pip through a proxy using [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)' `easy_install` by setting the same environment variables.

Windows:

```
set http_proxy=http://proxy.myproxy.com
set https_proxy=https://proxy.myproxy.com
easy_install pip
```

Linux/OS X:

```
export http_proxy=http://proxy.myproxy.com
export https_proxy=https://proxy.myproxy.com
sudo -E easy_install pip
```

Then once it's installed, use:

```
pip install --proxy="user:password@server:port" packagename
```

From the [pip man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/pip.1.html):

> --proxy
>              Have pip use a proxy server to access sites. This can be specified
>              using "user:password@proxy.server:port" notation. If the password
>              is left out, pip will ask for it.

Comment: Your answer appears to assume pip is already installed, I have not successfully installed pip yet. Instrucutions say to run the get-pip.py script, but I am getting connection timeout, which is what I am having troubles with.

Comment: @Damascusi, would you mind telling me if that env var worked for the get-pip script so I can update the answer appropriately?

Comment: @BenBurns your solution requires easy_install to be installed, however I need a proxy to install that aswell...

Comment: I tired installing it, with http_proxy and https_proxy set, but I get the error `(407) Proxyauthentifizierung erforderlich`, since our proxy uses usernames and passwords. I tried setting `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` using the `username:password@proxy` notation, but I still got the error.

Comment: Do you know what kind of authentication your proxy requires? I think the only type of proxy authentication supported here will be http digest or http basic (as supported by the user:pass encoding in the url). The best solution I can suggest is to run a local proxy (such as privoxy) bound to the loopback interface (so you can only connect to it from your own machine) which in turn hands requests off to your true proxy (and therefore manages auth for you)

Comment: Also, there are now quite a few ways to install pip as compared to when this question was asked/answered. You might do better to use a more "offline" install method.

Comment: I was successful in installing with get-pip.py behind a proxy - even with an ssh tunnel into the server from a jump server. `export https_proxy=https://localhost:18080 ; export http_proxy=http://localhost:18080 ; export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy` then `python get-pip.py`

Comment: Thanks a ton, I've updated my answer accordingly and upvoted yours below!

Comment: Does `set http_proxy=http://proxy.myproxy.com` reflect the proxy globally in the system or to a specific directory only?

Comment: @cs1193 the proxy will be set for all subsequent applications which are launched from that particular shell

Answer (score 11):

On my network just setting http_proxy didn't work for me. The following points were relevant.

1 Setting http_proxy for your user wont be preserved when you execute sudo - to preserve it, do:

```
sudo -E yourcommand
```

I got my install working by first installing cntlm local proxy. The instructions here is succinct : http://www.leg.uct.ac.za/howtos/use-isa-proxies

Instead of student number, you'd put your domain username

2 To use the cntlm local proxy, exec:

```
pip install --proxy localhost:3128 pygments
```

Answer (score 6):

You can install `pip` (or any other package) with `easy_install` almost as described in the first answer. However you will need a `HTTPS` proxy, too. The full sequence of commands is:

```
set http_proxy=http://proxy.myproxy.com
set https_proxy=http://proxy.myproxy.com
easy_install pip
```

You might also want to add a port to the proxy, such as `http{s}_proxy=http://proxy.myproxy.com:8080`

Answer (score 1):

You can try downloading the Windows binaries for pip from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pip.

For using pip to download other modules, see [@Ben Burn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11727032/1165522).

Answer (score 1):

For installing pip with get-pip.py behind a proxy I went with the steps below. My server was even behind a jump server.

From the jump server:

```
ssh -R 18080:proxy-server:8080 my-python-server
```

On the "python-server"

```
export https_proxy=https://localhost:18080 ; export http_proxy=http://localhost:18080 ; export ftp_proxy=$http_proxy
python get-pip.py
```

Success.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd C:\Python34\Scripts

set HTTP_PROXY= DOMAIN\User_Name:Passw0rd123@PROXY_SERVER_NAME_OR_IP:PORT#

set HTTP_PROXY= DOMAIN\User_Name:Passw0rd123@PROXY_SERVER_NAME_OR_IP:PORT#

pip.exe install PackageName
```