# Set Proxy in pip.py

Tags: python, proxy, centos, pip

How can I export my Proxyserver in the pip file for python?

```
 set http_proxy=http://someserver.com:someport
```

does not work :/

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This answer may help you:

- [Using PIP behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy)

Generally `pip` accepts `--proxy` argument, but CNTLM Windows proxies will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this old thread now as it still appears near the top of a google search with no real answer.

On windows the proxy parameters for pip do not seem to work properly and it is necessary to set environment variables up before running pip. This also works with other command line applications like wget etc.

The proxy setting usually needs to have the username and password added to the variable to work correctly.

At the Windows command prompt enter:

set http_proxy=http://DOMAINNAME\username:password@proxyserver:port

and/or

set https_proxy=https://DOMAINNAME\username:password@proxyserver:port