# How to use pip with socks proxy?

Tags: macos, proxy, pip

I'm using `ssh -D` to create a socket proxy and want to know how to use `pip`(or `easy_install`) with it? I find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy) but that's an http proxy.

Also, please give me a solution works under OS X. (I tried [proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/mac/ver2.htm), it works with `pip install`, but not `sudo pip install`)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use socks proxifier, for example [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/).

Command pip will be like `proxychains pip install package_name`.

Or use [another proxifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers).

Comment: if you're coming here since 2020, you'll probably have better luck with https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng instead of the mentioned SourceForge link.

Comment: proxychains doesn't work for me for pip (or git) - but proxychains-ng did!
* proxychains *did* work for apt though...

Answer (score 33):

Easiest method, also works on many OS's:

```
pip install pysocks
pip install <yourpacakge> --proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:8123
```

Substitute socks4, and your own ip/port as needed.

Comment: "AssertionError: Not supported proxy scheme socks5"

Comment: Unfortunately, if you need a proxy to get `pip` connected, this is not going to work

Comment: @mark pip has a bootstrapping shell scripts that you can use with more traditional proxy params.  ie: `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py` .

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev  Did you try socks4?   Possibly you need a newer version of python for this to work (I typically use 3.6)

Comment: My solution was to install `python3-pysocks` via yum with appropriate SOCKS proxy settings in /etc/yum.conf, then run the second command.

Comment: do you mean `socks5://127.0.0.1:8123`?

Comment: hmm, it depends.   on my install the "://" doesn't work

Answer (score 6):

For CentOS, you can use privoxy to convert socks5 proxy to http proxy.

```
yum install privoxy
```

Then edit `/etc/privoxy/config`, at the end of the file, add:

```
forward-socks5 / 127.0.0.1:1080 .
```

It will convert socks5 proxy from `1080` to http proxy `8118`. Then you can specify the proxy in your pip config file:

```
[global]
proxy = 127.0.0.1:8118
```

DO NOT use `polipo`, as it is already deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

As other users have posted the following works well for using pip via a remote host:

```
# SOCKS4 proxy creation
ssh -D9999 <remote host URI>
# use pip with the previously created proxy connection (requires pysocks)
python3 -m pip install <package name> --proxy socks5:localhost:9999
```

**Bootstrapping**

*"But I need pysocks to run pip through a proxy and you can't connect to the pypi to download packages as I don't have functioning pip"*

One way to get around this is to download the pysocks wheel package on another machine:

```
python3 -m pip download pysocks
```

This will download the pysocks package to your machine. Transfer the *PySocks-x-x-x-py3-none-any.whl* file to the machine that requires proxy functionality and install:

```
python3 -m pip install PySocks*.whl
```

Answer (score 3):

Run these two commands:

```
pip install pysocks5
pip install --proxy socks5://[user:passwd@]proxy.server:port something
```

Comment: These days it appears the package is just `pysocks` and you can invoke it with socks4 or socks5 protocols.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, --proxy seems to work with http(s) proxy only.

From "pip --help"

```
--proxy <proxy>             Specify a proxy in the form
                          [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port.
```

Edit: I finally gave up sock proxy and run a java http proxy (jhttp2.sourceforge.net/‎) on my remote machine and use ssh -L port:localhost:port to forward the port to the remote machine and use that http proxy.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can try install proxychains-ng using

> brew install proxychains-ng

the can try make a socks5 proxy using ssh -D like

> ssh -D 12345 -fqN root@[your-vps-ip]

and use public-key or password to access your vps

then you have both proxychain and socks5.

Now edit /etc/proxychains.conf , simply add this line at the end of it

```
socks5  127.0.0.1 12345
```

and comment this

```
socks4  127.0.0.1 9050
```

Finally

> proxychains4 pip install [whateveryouwant]

Answer (score 0):

On Windows (mine was Win2012R2) I managed connecting through SOCKS5-proxy by doing those steps:

All-user-level-pip:

1. Adding this lines to pip.ini under "C:\ProgramData\pip":

   ```
   [global]  
   proxy = socks5:{proxy-ip}:{proxy-port}
   ```
2. Opening cmd.exe (maybe but not necessarily as administrator ... depends on your file-system configuration...)
   Setting proxy variables to "no-proxy" explicitly!!! ... like that:

   ```
   set http_proxy=no-proxy  
   set https_proxy=no-proxy
   ```
3. running for example `pip install your_module` and finally it works through the socks5-proxy specified in the pip.ini

For user-level-pip you need to place the pip.ini somewhere else according pip-documentation.