# Trouble installing applications via pip on windows

Tags: python, django, windows, pip

I get the following error when trying to install applications with pip.

```
    Collecting django
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 232, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 339, in run
      requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 333, in prepare_files
      upgrade=self.upgrade,
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 305, in find_requirement
      page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 783, in _get_page
      return HTMLPage.get_page(link, req, session=self.session)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 872, in get_page
      "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 473, in get
      return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 365, in request
      return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 461, in request
      resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
      r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 43, in send
      resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 337, in send
      conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 245, in get_connection
      proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 155, in proxy_manager_for
      **proxy_kwargs)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 265, in proxy_from_url
      return ProxyManager(proxy_url=url, **kw)
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 216, in __init__
      'Not supported proxy scheme %s' % proxy.scheme
  AssertionError: Not supported proxy scheme abden003
```

I have tried running the following commands, but get the same error in both cases (I have tried using both python and python3):

```
pip install django

pip install django --proxy http://abden003:password@proxy.server.addr:port

pip3 install django

pip3 install django --proxy http://abden003:password@proxy.server.addr:port
```

The problem is not with my proxy server, since I tried it in a Linux vm and it works fine.  It seems to be a problem with the windows version of pip.

I have tried the following but it did not fix the problem:

[pip, proxy authentication and "Not supported proxy scheme"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109264/pip-proxy-authentication-and-not-supported-proxy-scheme)

Comment: Is it just django, did you try to pip install something else as well?

Comment: Yes I have tried installing a few packages they all give the same error

Comment: This might have an answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109264/pip-proxy-authentication-and-not-supported-proxy-scheme

Comment: I have tried this, but it didn't fix the problem

Comment: Did you try uninstalling and reinstalling pip, also are you sure that you are using the latest version of python (2.7.x or 3.x)?

Comment: Fresh install of python, also it comes with pip (7.0.3)

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to fix the problem, it involved deleting a line of code.  If you look at the last error it says the following:

```
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py", line 216, in __init__
      'Not supported proxy scheme %s' % proxy.scheme
  AssertionError: Not supported proxy scheme abden003
```

Go to:

```
 C:\Python34\lib\sitepackages\pip\_vendor\requests\packages\urllib3\poolmanager.py
```

in my case I went to C:\Python34\Lib.. instead of C:\Python34\lib

Open the poolmanager.py file, and delete line 215 which says the following:

```
    #  assert proxy.scheme in ("http", "https"), \
    #    'Not supported proxy scheme %s' % proxy.scheme
```

I don't if this line was accidentally left in, but removing fixed the problem and I was able to install packages via pip

Answer (score -2):

you should run `pip install django` in command prompt instead of python shell.