# use pip intall virtualenv:ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'))

Tags: virtualenv

I installed `virtualenv` with `pip`, but I'm getting this error:

```
[root@szlnginx_proxy bin]# ./pip install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'))': /simple/virtualenv/
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem and I was able to resolve it by adding "nameservers" to `/etc/resolv.conf`. For a list of nameservers and further information on resolv.conf you can check out:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Resolv.conf.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. In my case it was that I had a proxy and had not set the environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`.

If you suspect you have this issue you can look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19962913/4708657)