# How to install pywinrm

Tags: python

I am running centos6 Python 2.6 and am trying to install `pywinrm` but not am not successful. I have also tried:

```
pip install http://github.com/diyan/pywinrm/archive/master.zip#egg=pywinrm
```

but the link is broken (archive folder removed)

Installed Packages

```
python.x86_64       2.6.6-64.el6        @anaconda-CentOS-201508042137.x86_64/6.7
```

The pip install shows the following:

```
[root@linux-s3-vm1 ~]# pip install pywinrm
Collecting pywinrm
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'))': /simple/pywinrm/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'))': /simple/pywinrm/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use pip intall virtualenv:ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution'))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30276447/use-pip-intall-virtualenvprotocolerrorconnection-aborted-gaierror-3-tem)

Answer (score 0):

Here are my steps for getting pywinrm installed. I'm running Fedora 24 but it might be close enough (if one or two of these packages fail to install, you may just need to Google around for your platform's equivalent). Also, I'm using dnf. You might be using yum. Just replace "dnf" with "yum" in the command below:

```
sudo dnf install openssl-devel redhat-rpm-config krb5-devel krb5-workstation python-devel python2 python-pip python-kerberos authconfig git
```

-

```
pip install kerberos pykerberos requests_kerberos pywinrm
```