# pip failing to install packages behind a proxy

Tags: python-2.7, proxy, pip

Am new to python. As part of my project setup I tried to install soem python packages using pip as

```
pip install --proxy="uname:pwd@ip:port" pymssql
```

But am getting following log in pip.log

```
page http://pypi.python.org/simple/pymssql
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/pymssql: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/pymssql when looking for download links for pymssql
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for pymssql
  Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for pymssql:
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/pymssql/
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/pymssql/
  Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/pymssql/: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
  Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/pymssql/ when looking for download links for pymssql
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pymssql
No distributions at all found for pymssql
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 223, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 954, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\index.py", line 152, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for pymssql
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using pip behind a proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy)

Comment: @DušanMaďar that answer seems specific to CNTLM proxies

Answer (score 2):

just set this 2 variables on your environment (linux or windows):

```
http_proxy    http://user:passarod@proxy:port
https_proxy    http://user:passarod@proxy:port
```

Comment: This problem still exists today! But this solves it although I wish the `--proxy` switch worked as expected.