# Airflow installation successfull, but unable to run it

Tags: python, pip, airflow

> C:\Python27\Scripts>airflow initdb
>   'airflow' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>
> C:\Python27\Scripts>airflow init
>   'airflow' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

[image]

> C:\Python27\Scripts>airflow webserver -p 8080
>
> 'airflow' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I am trying to install in Windows 7 machine and I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Without further knowledge about Python in Windows. Have you added airflow to your PYTHON_PATH?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Airflow doesn't officially support running on Windows.  From my limited testing with it I was unable to get it running, in the end I just set everything up on a Linux VM.  https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/airbnb_airflow/JrE-aJDLm5w, discusses the modifications the author tried to get Airflow running on Windows but there were still errors. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32378495/2109767 shows a method that used to work, but from the comments and my test of this method it seems to no longer work.  Good lucky trying, if you succeed in getting Airflow running on Windows post back as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could also try to install it directly on Google Cloud Platform as a windows user: https://lemag.sfeir.com/installing-and-using-apache-airflow-on-the-google-cloud-platform/.