# Airflow - Failed normally launch first command

Tags: anaconda, conda, airflow

I installed Airflow through

> pip install apache-airflow

in Conda Promt. It's installed normally, but when i'm trying to launch this command through Conda Prompt:

> airflow initdb

It gives me an error that "airflow is not an internal or external command, executable program, or batch file"

How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are running this in windows, you can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42510906/840984

In short: **Airflow doesn't officially support running on Windows**