# Airflow DAG development in Windows PyCharm

Tags: windows, pycharm, airflow

I'm trying to setup airflow based application workspace in Windows Desktop with PyCharm.

Have installed PyCharm, Python 2.7, added airflow to Project Interpreter as well.

Tried to setup the very base example from https://pythonhosted.org/airflow/tutorial.html. When the Python script (tutorial.py) is executed, it just goes within few seconds without performing any operation.

`AIRFLOW_HOME` is also set `C:/Users/muthu/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python27/site-packages/airflow/` while submitting the script.

```
Console Messages:
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/muthu/MyWork/non-sync/python-workspace/dags/tutorial.py
[2017-03-16 01:48:42,349] {__init__.py:36} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Airflow on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378494/how-to-run-airflow-on-windows)

Answer (score 3):

Airflow doesn't run on Windows. I spent a couple days trying to get it running with MinGW, and also tried git bash with no luck. Airflow uses some python modules that are not available on Windows.

I solved this by using Virtual Box with Linux Mint and had airflow running in a few hours.