# Can I run Airflow on Windows?

Tags: python, airflow

I have researching for a few hours now but I cannot confirm If as of October 2017, you can run airflow on Windows. I have installed it using Python package "pip install airflow" but I cannot initialize it or even see the version, which I assume that it cannot run on Windows.

Comment: Please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378494/how-to-run-airflow-on-windows

Comment: Hi @chengzhi m Thank you for the comment. As I mentioned, I have been searching but I cannot confirm as of 2017 if they offer airflow on Windows user. The Stackoverflow link was way back 2015 so I am wondering if there are any updates. I do not know why this question have been "down voted"/ "unacceptable". Sad

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We make heavy use of airflow, and we use VM's running Linux to get it running. We have Windows machines, but have to use VM's or mount drives on Linux/Mac boxes to get it to work. As far as I know it's not even on the road map to have Airflow run on Windows.

So, long answer short: No, even as of October 2017 airflow runs only on Unix based systems (it uses some python libraries that only work for unix underneath), and it's unlikely that anytime soon it will support Windows.

Comment: Thank you so much @jhnclvr , definitely clears up my uncertainty if they release any updates. Really appreciate it!

Comment: as of January 2019 does this still stand? Not workaround to make airflow work for windows in not a so complicated manner?

Comment: If you are running a Windows version before 10, you need a VM.
I run it now on Windows 10 using Docker. I still prefer VM as the best way and am considering switching back to VM after trying it. Even in a VM I use Docker, and Docker works a lot better on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link mentioned below. All in all, it's possible with a workaround, but it's always recommended to proceed via docker or VM instead of doing it directly. 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/airbnb_airflow/JrE-aJDLm5w

Comment: this information is now out of date.  see the accepted answer.