# Airflow installation issue on Windows 7

Tags: airflow

How to install Airflow on Windows 7? getting below error while installing it using `pip install apache-airflow` :

```
    ---------------------------------------- Command "c:\users\shrgupta5\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe
-u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\SHRGUP~1\\AppData\\Loca l\\Temp\\pip-build-_yptw7sa\\psutil\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open) (__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __fi le__, 'exec'))" install
--record C:\Users\SHRGUP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-_cwm0n u7-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed
--compile" fail ed with error code 1 in C:\Users\SHRGUP~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-_yptw7sa\ psutil\
```

Comment: maybe describe what attempts you have done to install it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Airflow on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378494/how-to-run-airflow-on-windows)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't bother trying to install Airflow on windows, even after you install it successfully you cannot run the `airflow` script due to a dependency on the unix-only module `pwd`

Answer (score 2):

You can run Airflow on Windows by using the Docker setup from puckel https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow.

- Use VirtualBox and Docker Toolbox(legacy) and [setup a docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/#create-a-machine) on your Windows computer (`docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-cpu-count "2" --virtualbox-memory "2048"  default`)
- make sure to fork puckels git repo underneath c:/Users/yourusername/documents otherwise mounting of DAGS won't work
- You should now be able to spin up Airflow e.g. by using the celery-executor setup with `docker compose -f docker-compose-CeleryExecutor.yml up -d`

I have setup a environment where I develop the DAGs on Windows, test them within the dockercontainer and then push the Dockerimage to Linux to production. I have added a more detailed [tutorial here](https://marcelhama.de/software%20engineering/2018/04/29/airflow-docker-windows.html).

Answer (score 0):

Airflow cannot be installed on Windows within the standard command prompt.

You need to use bash and afterwards change the config:

[How to run Airflow on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378494/how-to-run-airflow-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Download the source of airflow from pypi:
https://pypi.org/project/airflow/#files

Unzip and edit setup.cfg, then go to the `install_requires` section and change the version of psutil with the following: `'psutil>=5.4.7',`

Finally, run `python setup.py install` in the source directory