# Apache Airflow : airflow initdb results in "ImportError: No module named json"

Tags: json, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04, airflow

On Ubuntu 16.04 with Python 2.7 default version, I am trying to install Apache airflow but ran into several issues and currently I see on

```
apache initdb 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 21, in <module>
    from airflow import configuration
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from flask_admin import BaseView
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_admin/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base import expose, expose_plugview, Admin, BaseView, AdminIndexView  # noqa: F401
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from flask import Blueprint, current_app, render_template, abort, g, url_for
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .app import Flask
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 69, in <module>
    from .wrappers import Request
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/wrappers.py", line 14, in <module>
    from werkzeug.wrappers.json import JSONMixin as _JSONMixin
ImportError: No module named json
```

Tried these things till now:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev
```

```
sudo pip install -U Werkzeug==0.14.1

sudo pip install -U Jinja2==2.10.1
```

Also tried

```
pip install jsonate

pip install json # (this did not work)
```

```
 python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> exit()
```

Nothing worked so far.

Comment: So running ```$ sudo pip install --upgrade Flask ``` worked for me with the airflow initdb.as suggested by Israel below.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just upgrade flask. You can use this command:

`sudo pip install --upgrade Flask`

Comment: More details here https://lists.apache.org/x/thread.html/fdb24fe0249b856926195cb19323383a4636ee0b0c398e376dce28ed@%3Cdev.airflow.apache.org%3E

Comment: Do you happen to know what version of Flask it is upgrading to?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is known, and is described here, in the [ASF Mail Archives](https://lists.apache.org/x/thread.html/fdb24fe0249b856926195cb19323383a4636ee0b0c398e376dce28ed@%3Cdev.airflow.apache.org%3E)

> We removed the incompatible Werkzeug library from apache master this
>   weekend. It caused Airflow installations to fail.

To resolve, manually install the werkzeug library in a correct version:

```
pip install werkzeug>=0.15.0
```

As explained in the mail list, this seems to be a temporary problem, and this solution is a workaround. The problem is encountered in version 1.10.3.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac while installing apache-airflow, I got following error:

ERROR: apache-airflow 1.10.3 has requirement jinja2<=2.10.0,>=2.7.3, but you'll have jinja2 2.10.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: apache-airflow 1.10.3 has requirement werkzeug<0.15.0,>=0.14.1, but you'll have werkzeug 0.15.4 which is incompatible.

Re-installing werkzeug and jinja worked for me.

```
pip install jinja2>=2.10.0
pip install werkzeug>=0.15.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**sudo** pip install --upgrade Flask worked for me