# How to fix "ImportError: No module named json" in Ubuntu?

Tags: python, json, ubuntu, airflow

I'm having issues with Apache Airflow. I'm working on Windows, so I had to install Ubuntu. It seemed to work at first but now it gives me "ImportError: No module named json" when I run:

```
airflow initdb
```

Previously I did:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install apache-airflow
```

After that, I get python2.7.15+

I'm not sure what I actually did wrong, as I've already managed to run Airflow, but then I had to reset everything and redo. And now I have this problem with json.
Would be really grateful if somebody could help me with it.

Comment: What Python version?

Comment: Show us the full output of the call!

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923003/apache-airflow-airflow-initdb-results-in-importerror-no-module-named-json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Airflow : airflow initdb results in "ImportError: No module named json"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923003/apache-airflow-airflow-initdb-results-in-importerror-no-module-named-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just upgrade flask:

```
pip install --upgrade Flask
```

Comment: I know that Airflow committers discussing it in email list right now. Best way to stick version of Werkzeug

Comment: Could you provide a pointer to that email list? And why not just upgrade Werkzeug instead of all of Flask? Also, is this a bug reported in Werkzeug or Flask that can be found somewhere (e.g., in their respective repository issue lists)?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5535/files and https://lists.apache.org/x/thread.html/fdb24fe0249b856926195cb19323383a4636ee0b0c398e376dce28ed@%3Cdev.airflow.apache.org%3E