# try to run airflow on databricks but got error

Tags: python, azure, airflow, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to use airflow on databricks.

I have installed apache-airflow 1.10.6 from https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/.

I am using python3.6 on databricks.

But, I got error:

```
 import airflow

  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.wrappers.json'; 'werkzeug.wrappers' is not a package
```

I have tried the followings:
    [Apache Airflow : airflow initdb results in "ImportError: No module named json"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56923003/apache-airflow-airflow-initdb-results-in-importerror-no-module-named-json)

[Apache Airflow : airflow initdb throws ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.wrappers.json'; 'werkzeug.wrappers' is not a package error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56933523/apache-airflow-airflow-initdb-throws-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-wer)

But, I still got the same problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** By default, "Airflow" and its dependency is not installed on the databricks.

You need to install the package explicitly.

**Dependency installation:** Using Databricks library utilities.

```
dbutils.library.installPyPI("Werkzeug")
```

[image]

You can install the packages in different methods.

**Method1:**  Installing external packages using pip cmdlet.

**Syntax:** `%sh /databricks/python3/bin/pip install <packagename>`

```
%sh
/databricks/python3/bin/pip install apache-airflow
```

[image]

**Method2:** Using Databricks [library utilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0oFw.png)

**Syntax:**

```
dbutils.library.installPyPI("pypipackage", version="version", repo="repo", extras="extras")
dbutils.library.restartPython()  # Removes Python state, but some libraries might not work without calling this function
```

To install apache-airflow using databricks library utilities use the below command.

```
dbutils.library.installPyPI("apache-airflow")
```

[image]

**Method3:** GUI Method

Go to **Clusters** => **Select Cluster** => **Libraries** => **Install New** => **Library Source** "**PyPI**" => Package "**apache-airflow**" => **Install**

[image]

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.

---

Do click on "Mark as Answer" and Upvote on the post that helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members.

Comment: This doesn't seem directly related; OP's error stems from `airflow` trying to import a dependency, so `airflow` has to already be installed.

Comment: @AKX Updated the answer with the dependency missing.

Comment: I tried to run "import dbutils; dbutils.library.installPyPI("Werkzeug")", got error: AttributeError: module 'dbutils' has no attribute 'library'

Comment: @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT, I have also tried method3, but it does not work, I still get the same error. thanks

Comment: i got my issue resolved by first first method. god bless u my friend... and god bless stackoverflow