# Can't copy airflow local DAG to docker container's dags folder (Windows)

Tags: windows, docker, airflow

I was trying out setting up Airflow through Windows docker, found a good one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59368063/2085454, but got stuck in the step to copy local DAG to docker `docker cp sample_dag.py containerName:/usr/local/airflow/dags`

the command I'm using here was `docker cp Desktop\test_dag.py naughty_bolbs:/usr/local/airflow/dags`, the terminal shows nothing when running this command and I can't find any copied DAGs in the container, "naughty_bolbs" is the container's name.

This .py file works well when I was running it locally on Mac. So the file itself should not be a problem.

Do you know how can I copy local DAG to the container's dags folder successfully on Windows?

Comment: Those answers are outdated, definetly check the official docker-compose setup from Airflow: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html

Comment: The guidance there doesn't work for windows...