# Connection ssh via python in a Windows System

Tags: python, ssh

I am a beginner in python development.
In fact , I want to make an ssh connection through a python code ,
do you have an idea?

Comment: This could do with some editing - are you asking, is there a python library which can open (and interact with..?) an SSH connection?

Comment: There are several ways to do it.  For help, use [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+ssh).  It is one of the most helpful resources on the internet.

Comment: I try to install paramiko but i have an error , i search in net but no solution

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using **[fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/)** module. It's rather simply to use, for example:

```
from fabric.api import env, run

env.host_string = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
env.user = 'username'
env.password = 'password'

run('ls -l')
```

That's just a simple example, but it should get you started.

Comment: I try to do this but i have this error :    No module named fabic.api

Comment: @ibtissem: you have to install it first bacause it is not included in Python's standard library. Try `pip install -U fabric` at you terminal.

Comment: Sorry but i have a problem with the command pip because i have a proxy and i'am in a work environnement

Comment: I try with paramiko but i have ap roblem "cannot import name "util" " ,have you any idea about this ?

Comment: You can try to use `pip` behind a proxy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy. Or you can download required packages manually from https://pypi.python.org.

Comment: thanks , but  could you tell me how to download required packages manually?