# Why are all installs via pip are failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

During [Python 3.4.4](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-344/) installation on Windows 7, I checked PIP and "add to Path." Every library I've tried to install via pip has so far resulted in "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement  (from versions:) No matching distribution found for wheel." I've also tried installing pip by downloading and running the get-pip.py file, but this results in the same error message when it tries to install wheel.

Are there any ideas why this is happening? Thanks ahead of time.

Edit 1: Added OS

Comment: Did you use `pip3` or `pip`? What is your OS?

Comment: @warmoverflow As far as I know, I think I'm using pip. My OS is Windows 7.

Comment: If you're using Linux, you may need sudo permissions unless you're doing a `--user` install.

Comment: What did you try to install?

Comment: @Sandy, add the exact syntax for one of the commands that failed with `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ...`, that usually means you used a package that simply does not exist

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Initially I was trying to install python future. When that failed, I installed this from their github page

Comment: @BhargavRao After running the upgrade command, I get the message "Requirement already up-to-date"

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Tried to install pip future by running `pip install future` resulting in "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement (from versions:) No matching distribution found for future."

Comment: @Sandy, is it the same for all packages?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Other packages I've tried installing include wheel (which had issues when I installed via the get-pip.py script) and importlib

Comment: @Sandy, just try `pip install https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/archive/master.zip`

Comment: is it a corporate computer by any chance?

Comment: @bvmcode yes, it's a corporate computer

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, ran that and got a number of exceptions. One possibly noteworthy error from running that command is this `pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)`

Comment: Ah ok,  sounds like you have a ca-certificates issue.  Run `python -mrequests.certs`, you may need to install Certifi https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi

Comment: Download https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/r/requests/requests-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=58a444aaa02780ad01983f5f540e67b2 and try installing with pip same with https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/c/certifi/certifi-2016.2.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=409448ee124f3159d912e4e155b034b0

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with my corporate PC. I recommend just downloading the wheel or tar file for what you want to install

For example, installing BeautifulSoup
Wheel file downloaded from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4.
Save in python34 directory.
Then CD to the python34 directory and then execute

```
python –m pip install beautifulsoup4-4.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
```

For a more permanent and sophisticated solution see the below link in regard to using CNTLM: 
[Using pip behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy)