# Unable to install Python-openstackclient

Tags: python, openstack

I am trying to install python-openstackClient for swift on Windows machine.
It gives me the below error:

`C:\Program Files\Python27\Scripts>pip install python-openstackclient
Collecting python-openstackclient
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/python-openstackclient/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/python-openstackclient/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/python-openstackclient/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/python-openstackclient/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/python-openstackclient/
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/python-openstackclient/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/python-openstackclient/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/python-openstackclient/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/python-openstackclient/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/python-openstackclient/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-openstackclient (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for python-openstackclient`

Comment: Do you use a proxy to access the internet?

Comment: Yes I'm using proxy.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14150397/1032785

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using pip behind a proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy)

Comment: Adding proxy to the install command helped start the download but the installion failed with below error :       ` Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pbr/: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it -- Some packages may not be found!
 Couldn't find index page for 'pbr' (maybe misspelled?)
 Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it -- Some packages may not be found!`