# pip install how to set user-agent

Tags: pip

At work, I'm behind a proxy.
Only Browsers may pass the proxy.
Is there a way, to make pip install pretend being another user-agent?

Analogies:

```
curl -A $USER_AGENT
git config --global http.useragent $USER_AGENT
```

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: If I recall correctly, we made pip allow to pass the proxy

Comment: the problem is not the proxy, is to change the user agent. In my proxy only firefox its allowed to use it, by change user agent of an application it can be solved, but I can't find any solution to pip.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer your exact question, but have a look at this: [Using pip behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy)

Comment: I know that question. It is not helpful for the problem at hand

Answer (score 0):

using the environment variable PIP_USER_AGENT_USER_DATA to include a JSON-encoded string in the user-agent variable used in pip’s requests.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).