# Numpy installing with python3.5 pip

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.5

I got many probelms to install numpy package. When i execute pip commande

```
pip install numpy
```

I get the following errors

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/numpy/Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for numpy

When i use `easy_insall` command, i get the following errors

> Searching for numpy timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
>   Couldn't find index page for 'numpy' (maybe misspelled?)
>   Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
>   Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
>   Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: timed out -- Some packages may not be found!
>   No local packages or download links found for numpy
>   error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('numpy')

And when i employ manual packages adding

```
python setup.py install
```

I get the following errors:

```
Running from numpy source directory.
Cythonizing sources
numpy/random\mtrand\randint_helpers.pxi.in has not changed
Processing numpy/random\mtrand\mtrand.pyx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'Cython'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Hazem\Python packages\numpy\tools\cythonize.py", line 70, in process_pyx
    r = subprocess.call(['cython'] + flags + ["-o", tofile, fromfile])
  File "C:\Users\Hazem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 560, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\Hazem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Hazem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Hazem\Python packages\numpy\tools\cythonize.py", line 220, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Hazem\Python packages\numpy\tools\cythonize.py", line 216, in main
    find_process_files(root_dir)
  File "C:\Hazem\Python packages\numpy\tools\cythonize.py", line 208, in find_process_files
    process(cur_dir, fromfile, tofile, function, hash_db)
  File "C:\Hazem\Python packages\numpy\tools\cythonize.py", line 167, in process
    processor_function(fromfile, tofile)
  File "C:\Hazem\Python packages\numpy\tools\cythonize.py", line 81, in process_pyx
    raise Exception('Cython failed')
Exception: Cython failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 391, in <module>
    setup_package()
  File "setup.py", line 374, in setup_package
    generate_cython()
  File "setup.py", line 212, in generate_cython
    raise RuntimeError("Running cythonize failed!")
RuntimeError: Running cythonize failed!
```

Need help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always download the [Numpy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.11.2/) installer

Comment: I did, and i executed the command manually as i said. But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

The error with pip shows you have a pip connection problem. I think you did not set your proxy correctly when trying to run pip install. Please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy). You may try  --proxy option for pip. Otherwise, I don't suggest any manual install for numpy.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the reason is network ,you can try once again.  (it worked for me)