# How to set proxy for terminal in ubuntu?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, proxy, virtualbox

**My scenario:**

I am trying to install python and postgresql in my newly installed ubuntu which runs through virtualbox on windows 7. It uses my companys network and I have set the proxy in the network settings of ubuntu.

I can browse and download using mozilla(ubuntu) with no problem.

**Problem:**

But when I try to install packages using terminal, it just stops at 0%. It tries various IP's, still at 0%
[my terminals screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNtbv.png)

[update] - it ended in unable to connect to IP

**Tried:**

I have already tried export proxy settings through

> sudo -H gedit /etc/profile.d/proxy.sh

and updated the file with

> export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyhost:port/

(also I've set for https)

Please let me know what's the problem going on ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using pip behind a proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To Set Proxy in Ubuntu:

Edit the **/etc/apt/apt.conf** file and add the following:

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://ProxyHOST:ProxyPORT/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://ProxyHOST:ProxyPORT/";
```

Hope it Helps.. :)

Answer (score 6):

This will be very simple . I have created a python 3 script for this

[proxy_configuration](https://github.com/nityanandagohain/proxy_configuration.git)

download it and run it . You can set and remove system wide proxy very quickly.

steps:
1) Download in zip and extract it.
2) open terminal and navigate to the folder where you have extracted the file.
3) type the following commands 
   chmod +x proxy.py 
   sudo ./proxy.py

cheers!.

Comment: The best answer so far. I always had problem setting system wide proxy. My web browser would run fine but my terminal often could not install or update anything. Browsed through hundreds of answers but none of them worked. Finally your solution worked. Thank you so so much.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer,

Please click [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89437/how-to-install-packages-with-apt-get-on-a-system-connected-via-proxy)

export option doesn't work for this kinda scenario

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal Then go to directory /etc/apt/apt.conf.d using

`cd /etc/apt/apt.conf.d`

and then create a new file named proxy.conf with root privileges using

`sudo gedit proxy.conf`

Now copy and paste the following

`Acquire::https::proxy "http://username:password@Port_ip:Port_Number/";`

`Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://username:password@Port ip:Port_Number/";`

Be sure to replace Port_ip and Port Number with the one provided by your office or network administrator