# ConnectTimeoutError installing Tensorflow on windows

Tags: proxy, tensorflow, installation

I'm triying to install Tensorflow, and I get the following:

```
    C:\>pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
    Collecting tensorflow
      Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 
ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000240DAD78BA8>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/tensorflow/
```

I've also tried to install it downloading the .whl on the GitHub repository, and I get the same kind of error:

```
C:\>pip3 install tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\tensorflow-1.1.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Collecting bleach==1.5.0 (from tensorflow==1.1.0)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001FEE571BCC0>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/bleach/
```

My PC is connected to my university's network which need a HTTP proxy configuration. Could it be the problem? How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

So pip work abruptly behind proxy for that you can refer [Using pip behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy)

But for your alternate you can download Tensorflow wheel from ([Python 2 CPU](https://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-matrix-cpu/TF_BUILD_IS_OPT=OPT,TF_BUILD_IS_PIP=PIP,TF_BUILD_PYTHON_VERSION=PYTHON2,label=cpu-slave/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/pip_test/whl/tensorflow-1.1.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl))

For other Python Version or CPU/GPU 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow#installation