# pip install module over proxy firewall

Tags: proxy, installation, pyinstaller, python-module

pip install with proxy firewall.

Someone referred me into looking at proxy and how I can put in arguments to get pass the proxy server and install the said python module. One of the link I found suggested I install CNTLM. >>
[Using pip behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy)

This suggestion needs installation which the proxy prevents so is not going to work.

Comment: What error did you see? What arguments did you use with pip?

Comment: error that it retry total =4, connect = none, read = none, redirect = none. after connection broken by newconnectionerror.  pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.verifiedhttpsconnection object at 0x00000000041592B0>: failed to established a new connection. errno 11004 getaddrinfo failed. Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement.   the arguments -- pip install --proxy=https://user@mydomain:port  somepackage.  but that error was not because of the argument. it was because of **pip install module** in command prompt pointing to script folder.

Comment: Did you already try with `sudo pip --proxy http://web-proxy.mydomain.com install somepackage`, as the most voted answer in your link suggests? Change your proxy accordingly.

Comment: change my proxy according to what, and what is mydomain ?  I typed it as you have it and I got error message sudo is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: You have to change it to your proxy IP address or URL.  Forget about sudo, use it as `pip install --proxy=<your_proxy_url>:<your_proxy_port> module`

Comment: but how do I know my proxy url and proxy port or ip address ?

Comment: You should ask for it to your network administrator.  As a hint, you can check your connections tab in either web browser you are using. If you are lucky enough, you'll find it there.  As long as you don't have it, pip won't know how to talk to the outside world.

Comment: Ok can I just go to command prompt and find the proxy URL and port rather than ask the administrator. I actually tried it by typing netsh winhttp show proxy and is suppose to show me the proxy address and port but it shows no proxy server. I went to IE and click on internet option and connections and LAN setting. Lan setting do not apply to dialup connections. Choose setting above for dialup connection. Please advise.

Comment: I got the proxy and port from admin. I use syntax pip --http://etc.etc.com:port install module. I get no such option to the URL and port.

Comment: Please be careful with the syntax. In your last post the proxy argument is missing. That's why pip is complaining.

Answer (score 0):

It worked with me :

```
pip --proxy http://[user]:[password]@proxy:[port] install module
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how do I know what is user, password and port, and how do I find out these information ?

Comment: If you use Anaconda, find the file .condarc, probably this file will have this informations.

Comment: Where does that file reside ?  I went to window and type the file name in the look up and it didn't show it exist.

Comment: What is user and password ?

Comment: I put my proxy URL and port in format pip install --"http://url.something.com:port module" and still get the same error message.