# I am getting Environmental error while installing robot framework in windows, event after allowing permissions to all in python root directory

Tags: python, selenium, testing, robotframework

I have given permissions to all by going to my python directory. I have even tried  running pip install mitmproxy but getting Please help me with a solution to this problem.

Please not:  I have allowed permissions to all in python root directory.

Error message on typing `pip install --no-cache-dir robotframework`:

Could not install packages due to an EnviromentError:

```
 [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python37-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\robot'
Consider using the '--user' option or check the permissions.
```

Please find the error message below after running the mitmproxy command:

```
Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\FUTURE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vdwgzzct\\brotlipy\\setup.py';f=getatt
enize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\FUTURE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-trng_sjo\insta
cord.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\FUTURE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vdwgzzct\brotlipy\
```

Comment: It seems like there is content missing here. Please don't try to upload any pictures of error messages. Instead, edit your question so that it contains the commands you have been running along with the error message **as text** (put into code formatting for better readability)

Comment: The error message tells you what to try to resolve the problem. Have you tried what it suggests?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install, as suggested with:

`pip install  --user robotframework`

Or, open a command window as Administrator, and install as in your first attempt.

Comment: Tried that. now i am getting:::      Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement robotframework (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for robotframework.

Comment: Searching with that error, got https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975280/pip-not-working-proxy
Maybe your in a restricted Internet environment.