# Python 3.6.2 pip3 install failed

Tags: python, pip

I installed Python 3.6.2 and PyCharm on my win7.
I tried to install packages, but PyCharm showed this error:

[image: Error from Pycharm]

Then I tried pip, but it failed again because of a connection failure:

[image: Error of pip]

It's a company laptop and it shouldn't be a security problem, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens typically when you are behind a proxy. You should try to configure pip to go through the proxy, as described here:

[Using pip behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy)

This helped me when I had a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks Gabor.  I tried some methods but they didn't work. It's probably because of our IT policy. But I changed the settings in PyCharm and I'm able to see the list of packages, but still can't install any of them.

Answer (score -1):

try this pip install --upgrade  --force-reinstall numpy