# I can't use pip on WSL Ubuntu

Tags: python, flask, pip

If I try to download Python packages with pip, following error messages come out.

```
nblizz@NBLIZZ-PC:~# pip3 install flask-restful
Collecting flask-restful
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/flask-restful/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/flask-restful/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/flask-restful/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/flask-restful/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', OSError(0, 'Error'))': /simple/flask-restful/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement flask-restful (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for flask-restful
```

None of these solutions work.

- Re-install pip
- Re-install WSL
- sudo pip3 install [package]
- pip3 install [package] with `root` account
- sudo -H pip3 install [package]
- pip install --user [package]

How do I install pip packages without errors?

Comment: Python does not come install by default in WSL. I guess, you will have to install python3 first. Can you check if python is working? You can follow the articles here for more help

1. https://medium.com/@rhdzmota/python-development-on-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-17a0fa1839d

2. https://medium.com/@sanajitghosh/run-python-codes-develop-ml-models-using-wsl-windows-10-40f8bb39fd45

Comment: Could you check the network connection `ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: @AdityaMishra I already installed Python to WSL and it works well. pip is the only problem.

Comment: @WaketZheng Result of `ping 8.8.8.8` is `64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=121 time=37.7 ms`

Comment: What's the output of `pip3 config list` ?

Comment: Try this: `pip install -i https://pypi.org/simple flask`

Comment: @Zeitounator It is `ERROR: unknown command "config"`.

Comment: @WaketZheng Sadly same error has occurred :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause was my Kaspersky application. It blocks every `pip`/`curl` executions.

Answer (score 3):

Tried all solutions, what solved the issue for me is to update the wsl by running from Windows CMD

```
wsl --update
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your pip: `python -m pip install –upgrade pip`; If its already updated proceed with any of the below two methods:

Method - I
You can download binary files from the below link
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Once the desired module (.whl file) is downloaded, open the command prompt on the downloaded location (you can do that by pressing shift + right click; select open command prompt/powershell here) and type `pip install your-package.whl`

Method - II
Go to https://pypi.org/ and search for the desired package.
Once downloaded, copy the package in the site-packages directory manually.

There are standard locations for site-package:

- Unix(pure): prefix/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages
- Unix(non-pure):exec-prefix/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages
- Windows:prefix\Lib\site-packages

To verify the download, by either of these methods, use the import statement on your console.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar but not identical problem with pip in WSL. (There is a diffrent error message).

```
$ pip3 install pytest
Collecting pytest
  Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3b23344eb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/pytest/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3b23a7e748>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/pytest/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3b23a7e940>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/pytest/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3b23a7e390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/pytest/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f3b23a7eb00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/pytest/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytest (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pytest
```

It turned out the WSL could't connect to any DNS server. `ping 8.8.8.8 -c 1` was successful, but `ping www.google.com -c 1` resulted in `Temporary failure in name resolution`. The reason for this was that `/etc/resolv.conf` was corrupted. I fixed it by replacing the corrupted content with the content below:

```
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, remove this line.
8.8.8.8
4.4.4.4
```

(Use e.g. nano for editing: `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`). I used Google's DNS servers above. WSL should update the DNS server automatically if the first line is included. After this pip worked normally again for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use google to search: `pip ProtocolError`

Someone said that:
SOLVED The issue was that my dorm firewall is blocking pip (pypi.python.org). Issuing the same command at work installs python packages correctly.

see: [PIP not working - proxy - Connection aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701622/pip-not-working-proxy-connection-aborted)

If this solution still not work for you, please tell more about your machine like

`pip --version`, `pip3 --version`, `python3 -V`, `python -V`, `cat /etc/issue`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue on WSL1 using conda environments. Eventually I found out that the solution is to have the same python version in conda's `base` environment as in the conda environment from which the `pip install` commands are being triggered.

`sudo pip install` should be avoided (even if as it seemingly solves the `NewConnectionError` error), as it will install packages globally and will mess up conda environments.

Answer (score 0):

Two issue that typcially get overlooked for me.

Add public dns entry to `/etc/resolv.conf`
`nameserver 8.8.8.8`

This will be overwritten on next startup unless you create a `/etc/wsl.conf` file with the below

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

The first issue is typically only a problem if wsl and windows have a time drift.

From Powershell...
`Get-Date; wsl date`

If your output doesn't match give it good old reboot. Usually fixes the issue for me.