# How to use conda/pip install to install packages behind a corporate proxy?

Tags: python, pip, conda

In R I can use

`install.packages("pkgName")`

to install a new package no problems. But when I tried python and do pip install package it fails with error

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None,
>   status=None)) after connection broken by
>   'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/pyarrow/

I think it's because pip doesn't know how to automatically detect the proxy (that's gets set in Internet Explorer) like R can.

Most of the info I find online either don't work or is just too complicated for someone without specialist knowledge to follow.

`conda install` fails as well.

Is there an easy fix to this?

Comment: I have never used Python on windows. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/14150397/937153 might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below command on windows command prompt or PowerShell:

`pip install --proxy DOMAIN\username:password@proxyserver:port packagename`

Replace the DOMAIN, username, password, proxy server and port with values specific to your system. This works for a windows 10 installation authenticated by Active Directory that is behind a corporate proxy server.