# Can't install pdfminer.six on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, installation, pdfminer

On my cmd window, I typed

```
pip install pdfminer.six
```

and it gives me these errors.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Eric Kim>pip install pdfminer.six
Collecting pdfminer.six
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x04435730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))': /simple/pdfminer-six/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x04435870>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))': /simple/pdfminer-six/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x04435410>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))': /simple/pdfminer-six/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x044355D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))': /simple/pdfminer-six/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x04435150>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed',))': /simple/pdfminer-six/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pdfminer.six (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pdfminer.six
```

I use Python 3.6 on Windows 10. What should I do? Is there any way that I can install this package without using pip? I want to use this link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer.six/20170720

I'm pretty new to programming, so I don't know much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a proxy problem, as the retry-error-message tells you. Your pip does not connect to the internet through the proxy.

Try `pip --proxy url:port pdfminer.six` with `url:port` beeing your proxy, e.g. `proxy.example.com:8080`.

If this is not working, try using another internet connection without a proxy to install packages via pip, or have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy), which has more answers regarding pip and proxy.