# How to install Python packages over SSH Port Forwarding?

Tags: python, ssh, pip

I am controlling a remote unit over SSH and OPENVPN.

On the remote unit I want to install some Python packages using `pip` but:

- the remote company firewall allows only traffic on port 22 (and not 443, needed by `pip`);
- DNS is not installed on the remote unit;
- I cannot modify any OPENVPN settings (or I would like to avoid this option as it means to access some remote sysadmin and try to convince him that the configuration must be changed);
- all systems are Linux (Ubuntu + Debian). Non Windows involved.

Stripping down hours of attempts (**I am not a system admin** and my knowledge on this subject is very limited), the idea was to open an obvious SSH port forwarding:

`ssh -R 9999:pypi.python.org:443 xxxx@XX.XX.XX.XX`

and then, on the remote unit play with `pip install`:

`pip install pymodbus==1.3.2 --proxy localhost:9999`

But this command returns:

```
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pymodbus==1.3.2
```

`/root/.pip/pip.log` is:

```
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pymodbus/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pymodbus/: connection error: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pymodbus/ when looking for download links for pymodbus==1.3.2
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/: connection error: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/ when looking for download links for pymodbus==1.3.2
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  URLs to search for versions for pymodbus==1.3.2:
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/pymodbus/1.3.2
  * https://pypi.python.org/simple/pymodbus/
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pymodbus/1.3.2
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pymodbus/1.3.2: connection error: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("''",))
  Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pymodbus/1.3.2 when looking for download links for pymodbus==1.3.2
  Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/pymodbus/
```

It is obvious the remote unit cannot read the index page on pypi.pthon.org because the connection is refused.

What is the **correct syntax** for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: According to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33611028/95735 you should specify it as `--proxy https://localhost:9999`

Comment: Piotr, yes, I forgot to tell that this was an attempt I already tried: `--proxy https://localhost:9999 --no-check-certificate` (the `--no-check-certificate` because otherwise it would complain that it is not present on `localhost`) but got the same `Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/`.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proxy is going to be tricky. I suggest that you scp the pip module source file and install it locally from source. Use
pip install package —download="/pth/to/downloaded/file” to get the package, scp it to the dest server and use pip install “/pth/to/scp/file”

Comment: I believe --download is deprecated. `pip download <package>` works though.

Comment: Not maintainable for multiple packages with multiple dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

It's look like my problem. after exploration, I have found a solution. 
And because in my region, pypi.python.org is slow, so I change my pip.conf and use pypi.douban.com/simple, as my index-url.  this website use http protocol. so in my solution. I use 80 port as my target port.

Problem:
I have two host. host1 could connect Pypi.douban.com. and host2 couldn't. 
but I can connect host2 in host1 through ssh.

so in host2, I open a tmux session and open a ssh tunnel by local port forwarding(not remote port forwarding):

```
ssh -L 9999:pypi.douban.com:80 username@host1
```

after this redirect, I can use

```
pip install scikit-learn --proxy localhost:9999
```

to install package in host2.

Comment: didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a reverse dynamic proxy. In your case, try:

- On your local machine

```bash
ssh -R 9999 username@remotehostname
```

- On the remote host

```
pip install packageName --proxy socks5:127.0.0.1:9999
```

For your reference: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179270/how-to-create-reverse-dynamic-ssh-port-forwarding