# Configuring Anaconda proxy works for conda and not for pip

Tags: python, anaconda

I have set a virtual environment with anaconda on windows 10
I set the .condarc file with proxy setting
the conda install commands work fine but the pip install (via same virtual env) does not work as cannot access network
what should be set especially for pip?

I put the proxy settings in the condarc

proxy_servers:
    http: http://myproxy.coo:8080
    https: https://myproxy.com:8081

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using pip behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip uses its own proxy configuration. Look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22229387/3594526) to learn how to configure pip to use a proxy server.

Comment: This should be a proposed duplicate, not an answer.