# can't install urllib3, having proxy in between using pip?

Tags: python, pip, urllib, urllib3

Basically I am trying to install urllib3 but I am countering below error:

```
 `C:\Python 3.7\Scripts>pip3.7.exe install urllib3
 Collecting urllib3
   Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
  after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection
 .VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x03285170>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed ou
 t. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/urllib3/
   Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
  after connection broken by      'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection
 .VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00D3E2B0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed ou
 t. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/urllib3/
   Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
  after connection broken by           'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection
 .VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x032AB610>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed ou
 t. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/urllib3/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
  after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection
 .VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x032AB670>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed ou
 t. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/urllib3/
   Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None))
  after connection broken by      'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection
 .VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x032AB5F0>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed ou
 t. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/urllib3/


pip3.7.exe install urllib3
   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib3 (from versions: )
 No matching distribution found for urllib3
```

**I Tried:** `pip3.7.exe install urllib3` and `pip install urllib3` both are having the same issue

FYI: I am located behind a proxy.

All replies are much appreciated

Comment: It looks like your computer just has a bad internet connection at the moment. Can you try turning the internet off and on again, then retry this and see what happens? Alternatively, try to install something else using `pip` and see if that has the same issue.

Comment: what version of python do you have? 3.7?

Comment: @user2906838 yes it's 3.7

Comment: Then probably there is no distribution of urllib3 for python 3.7, please check if it works with 3.6. It should work.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy after Disconnecting and connecting, still having the same issue, FYI: between there is a proxy so do I need to make any changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using pip behind a proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

You say you're using a proxy server on your machine. That is probably the problem, and it's why your error message says it's timing out. `pip` needs to be told about the proxy:

```
$ pip3.7.exe install urllib3 --proxy=http://name.of.proxy.com
```

at which point it will use the proxy and will complete its request. No guarantees what it will find, but the error message for that should be more helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution did not work for me. I am using Python 3.7.3