# docker fails to install dependencies

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I am learning docker while following this tutorial: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/

Everything seems okay but When I run **docker build --tag=learndocker .** it starts failing in the line that is supposed to install dependencies. Here is the error:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7fb5eee1f1d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)': /simple/click/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Click==7.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Click==7.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Here is my requirements.txt content:

```
Click==7.0
Flask==1.0.2
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pkg-resources==0.0.0
redis==3.2.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a DNS problem - see the comments on Dns settings here : https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/

> DNS settings
>
> DNS misconfigurations can generate problems with pip. You need to set your own DNS >server address to make pip work properly. You might want to change the DNS >settings of the Docker daemon.

Comment: I've tried that. Checking for my DNS address returns three addresses. I don't know which is which.
`IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.3.2`
`IP4.DNS[2]:                             192.168.3.14`
`IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.137.1`

Comment: I have tried to use all of the above DNS addresses and also left the DNS address part out but still getting the same error

Comment: Hmm... did you remember to restart the docker daemon after making changes to /etc/docker/daemon.json ?  and did you try adding googles dns server (8.8.8.8) ?

Comment: Problem solved. It was about adding the DNS addresses to daemon.json. I have 3 DNS addresses but I was only adding one. I added all of them and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with docker. `pip` is not able to connect to the remote servers. The most relevant error message is:

> Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',)'

Are you sure your internet connection is fine? If you are using a proxy, checkout [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy). However, it could also be that there is some temporary server outage.

Comment: Yes, my internet connection is fine. From the googling I've done, I'm not behind a proxy.