# How to download Python modules for school if proxy prevents pip from being able to download

Tags: python

I'm doing a school project which requires us to create a database application. I decided to use Python, utilising the tkinter, openpyxl and Pillow modules. Whilst working on this at home, I was able to create a functioning program, but it has been extremely difficult to do any work on it at school due to the proxy preventing pip from being able to download openpyxl and Pillow.

Is it possible for me to get the modules from my computer (Mac) to school (Windows) and set it up there, and if so, how?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447068/11044402

Comment: Have you tried [connecting to the proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy) when installing with pip?

Comment: `pip wheel` will (with similar syntax to `pip install`) create wheel files that can be installed with `pip install <wheelfile>`. But frankly it would be better to get the proxy fixed.

Comment: I just want to add that you are very likely to run into issues when trying to migrate python packages from one operating system to another, especially if they are using different versions of Python

Comment: @pistolpete Unfortunately, there's a second part to the proxy from some proprietary Windows software which prevents that.

Answer (score 0):

Windows installers are available [here](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/#files) if that helps. But I'd agree that you should fix the proxy. Also check out the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow) for Pillow.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just `pip` at home, then go to `<your python installation>\lib\site-packages` and store the modules you got on a thumb drive. Take the drive to school and go to the same directory and place the files in `site-packages`. If you can't write to that directory,  you could always place the modules alongside your modules and `import` them into your program.

Because you are on mac, it will be slightly different, but the path is very similar. Here's the official doc regarding:

https://docs.python.org/3.1/install/index.html#how-installation-works