# python: installing packages via pip behind corporate proxy server

Tags: python, installation, pip, http-proxy

I'm trying to install numpy (but this problem is replicated with everything i tried so far, including jupyer), using:

```
pip install --proxy=https://user:pass@name:port --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org numpy
```

getting this error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/numpy/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy
```

Not sure what to do next. 'No such file or directory'. It's all there under https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/. Is the proxy server interfering still? What can I do about that?

Comment: if you also have a os level proxy applied that might cause some issues. You can also manually dowload the whl file and install it vie pip

Comment: You mean from here:  https://github.com/numpy/numpy        ? That is a last resort I thought about but since there's more of these installs I have to do and the problem is happening with each one, I'm looking for a more general solution, if possible.

Comment: Have you tried [the suggestions from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy-with-cntlm)?

Comment: I mean my syntax already includes the proxy, like they're doing. So I though this is more of a version compatibility problem/there are som pre-requisite installs, but I read up on numpy and they say there's no pre-requisites other than python. I don't have python added to path yet, might that matter? Is that how numpy verifies if that pre-requisite is met?

Comment: @the_dude https://pypi.org/project/numpy/ also have you checked your environment variables?

Comment: I've got pip in environmental variables.