# error when installing with python on ubuntu

Tags: python, installation, pip

im encountered this error when installing with `pip install <package-name>`:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f41f935fdc0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /packages/09/3a/30e0af21d2f83dc1c45764910958b2d95ad9b8750d8c781ec8836105446f/cellrank-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/09/3a/30e0af21d2f83dc1c45764910958b2d95ad9b8750d8c781ec8836105446f/cellrank-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f41f935ff70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))
```

I ve tried with:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org 
<package-name>
```

but I get the same error! please help

Comment: Looks like a network error, are you able to connect to other web sites? Is this a really old version of Ubuntu?

Comment: yes I can connect, Im using ubuntu 20.4 on a new machine

Comment: So what does `host files.pythonhosted.org` or `dig files.pythonhosted.org` tell you?

Comment: What is `pip --version`?

Comment: Is there a chance the machine is behind a proxy server or a firewall? (This can happen often at a work place.)

Comment: @9769953 yes it could be. It s a work station

Comment: Perhaps you should check with your local sysadmins. Some information on pip behind a proxy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149422/using-pip-behind-a-proxy-with-cntlm and https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-a-proxy-server . If not through the sysadmins, you might also be able to find the name of a proxy server somewhere in your browser settings (if there is indeed a proxy in between).