# How to get pip to work behind a proxy server

Tags: python, proxy, pip

I am trying to use python package manager pip to install a package and it's dependencies from the internet. However I am behind a proxy in my college and have already set the `http_proxy` environment variable. But when I try to install a package like this:

```
pip install TwitterApi
```

I get this error in the log file:

```
Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/TwitterApi
Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/TwitterApi: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
Will skip URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/TwitterApi when looking for download links for TwitterApi
Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not fetch URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

I even tried setting my proxy variable explicitly like this:

```
pip install --proxy http://user:password@proxyserver:port TwitterApi
```

But I still get the same error. How do I get pip to work behind a proxy server.

Comment: can you browse to pypi.python.org in your browser?

Comment: Yes. I can browse the internet without a problem. I have also configured proxy for wget in the wgetrc file and `wget` seems to be working. Even `git` is working with some configuring of proxy. But `pip` keeps throwing the same error.

Comment: See this answer to a similar question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726881/how-to-set-an-http-proxy-in-python-2-7

Answer (score 152):

The pip's proxy parameter is, according to `pip --help`, in the form `scheme://[user:passwd@]proxy.server:port`

You should use the following:

```
pip install --proxy http://user:password@proxyserver:port TwitterApi
```

Also, the `HTTP_PROXY` env var should be respected.

*Note that in earlier versions (couldn't track down the change in the code, sorry, but the doc was updated [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/2b2ca40ccc44a3e1873f77b770b359e66349120b)), you had to leave the `scheme://` part out for it to work, i.e. `pip install --proxy user:password@proxyserver:port`*

Comment: Where's the difference?

Comment: Actually you have to specify (protocol is required):
`pip install --proxy http://user:password@proxyserver:port <package>`

Comment: In my case I have to specify the domain, like this: pip install --proxy DOMAIN\user:password@proxyserver:port <package>

Comment: I suppose you're connecting to a proxy authenticated by some kind of windows ActiveDirectory service. The domain is thus somehow part of the username. Be careful, you may need to escape `\` to avoid terminal char escaping (e.g. `\n` and the likes)

Comment: Obviously I meant escaping `\\`, but I can't edit now ;-)

Comment: most of the repos are have the URL started with https://
So better you also suggest to try https:// with proxy URL

Comment: Is the env var "HTTP_PROXY" or "http_proxy" (lowercase)? I set both in my env but wonder if both are necessary. Most of the articles and comments use "http_proxy" (lowercase).

Comment: In my case, I have to remove the *scheme ://* part for http proxy. I am using pip 21.2.4.

Answer (score 38):

At least for pip 1.3.1, it honors the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables. Make sure you define both, as it will access the PYPI index using https.

```
export https_proxy="http://<proxy.server>:<port>"
pip install TwitterApi
```

Comment: This didn't work on CentOS

Comment: This one works for the git-bash command-line in Windows 7 after setting the https_proxy variable in the terminal context.

Answer (score 26):

Old thread, I know, but for future reference, the --proxy option is now passed with an "="

Example:

```
$ sudo pip install --proxy=http://yourproxy:yourport package_name
```

Answer (score 18):

First Try to set proxy using the following command

```
SET HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.***.com:PORT#
```

Then Try using the command

```
pip install ModuleName
```

Comment: This worked for me when none of the other solutions did. Using Windows 7 Pro

Comment: @Plamen, thats because most of the pip repos start with https://   
All other answers suggests to use http_proxy, but in this case, you have set https_proxy

Answer (score 9):

On Ubuntu, you can set proxy by using

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port
export https_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port
```

or if you are having SOCKS error use

```
export all_proxy=http://username:password@proxy:port
```

Then run pip

```
sudo -E pip3 install {packageName}
```

Comment: Hello is the user name and password yours id on entreprise?

Comment: @abdoulsn It is the username and password you use login to proxy

Comment: Yes thanks I’ve got it it worked.

Answer (score 6):

at least pip3 also works without "=", however, instead of "http" you might need "https"

Final command, which worked for me:

```
sudo pip3 install --proxy https://{proxy}:{port} {BINARY}
```