# PIP how escape character # in password?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, http-proxy

want to continue question
[How to get pip to work behind a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080352/how-to-get-pip-to-work-behind-a-proxy-server/39206294#39206294)

I have Windows Server and Python 3.5 (64).

In password my user include #.

I try to use some solve:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python35\scripts\pip.exe" install --proxy http://proxy_user:pwd#123@proxy.su:1111 TwitterApi

"C:\Program Files\Python35\scripts\pip.exe" install --proxy "http://proxy_user:pwd#123"@proxy.su:1111 TwitterApi

"C:\Program Files\Python35\scripts\pip.exe" install --proxy http://"proxy_user:pwd#123"@proxy.su:1111 TwitterApi

"C:\Program Files\Python35\scripts\pip.exe" install --proxy http://proxy_user:"pwd#123"@proxy.su:1111 TwitterApi
```

BUT to get error

```
  File "c:\program files\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\package
s\urllib3\util\url.py", line 189, in parse_url
    raise LocationParseError(url)
pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to p
arse: proxy_user:pwd
```

How escape character # in this case?

Comment: try "pwd\#123", it may work.

Comment: have error: pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.LocationParseError: Failed to p
arse: proxy_user:pwd\

Comment: Try %23 in place of #

Comment: Nabeel Ahmed, thank you. Resolve: "C:\Program Files\Python35\scripts\pip.exe" install --proxy http://proxy_user:"pwd%23123"@proxy.su:1111 TwitterApi

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Quick way out**: Enter it in the encoded form i.e. `# -> %23`

OR

> A better way for pip to handle this might be to add a `--proxy-auth`
>   flag that takes : and does the encoding for the
>   user before adding it to the Proxy URL.

---

**Issue** - This is something not allowed:

> Strictly speaking, the literal # character is not valid in the
>   userinfo portion of a URI, according to RFC 3986, and should be
>   percent encoded. However, it's not exactly a surprise that many tools
>   handle this ok: there's clearly no actual ambiguity about that
>   character. Note, however, that if there were an @ symbol in the
>   password you'd definitely have to urlencode it: for that reason, it's
>   a good habit to get into to urlencode your passwords before they go
>   into URIs.

The response to a submitted issue [parse_url fails when given credentials in the URL with '/', '#', or '?'](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/814):

> [The RFC says specifically](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/814#issuecomment-197046251):
>
> The authority component is preceded by a double slash ("`//`") and is
>   terminated by the next slash ("`/`"), question mark ("?"), or number
>   sign ("`#`") character, or by the end of the URI. In other words, the
>   current behaviour is correct in expecting the authority to be
>   terminated by the first `/` (or ? or `#`) it finds after the preceeding
>   `//`. Am I sympathetic to people trying to use proxy URIs with pip?
>   Absolutely. I think hacking together something that violates the RFC
>   has the potential for nasty surprises later on.

---

Comment: You can use the w3schools tool also: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 3):

```
else examples
```

```
    $user = str_replace('@', '%40', $user);
    $pass = str_replace('%', '%25', $pass); // don't down! (%)
    $pass = str_replace('#', '%23', $pass);
    $pass = str_replace('@', '%40', $pass);
    $pass = str_replace(':', '%3a', $pass);
    $pass = str_replace(';', '%3b', $pass);
    $pass = str_replace('?', '%3f', $pass);
    $pass = str_replace('$', '%24', $pass);
    $pass = str_replace('!', '%21', $pass);
    $pass = str_replace('/', '%2f', $pass);
    $pass = str_replace('\'', '%27', $pass);
    $pass = str_replace('"', '%22', $pass);
```