# How can I execute a pip install from git if the branch I need starts with the # sign

Tags: git, pip

How can I execute a pip install from git if the branch I need starts with the # sign

I need to not separate it from the link text.
Now it is perceived as a separate sign (from the link)

Comment: You mean, when doing something like `pip install git+https://github.com/foo/bar@branch`?

Answer (score 0):

[URL-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it, that is, replace with `%23`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39207995/7976758

Answer (score 0):

Solution to bypass this problem: `git+http://gitlab.site.com/test@<hash>`