# EnvironmentError installing packages on public registry with private registry in pipconf

Tags: python, pip

I have a private PyPi registry that my company uses to host internal Python packages.  I have setup my machine to handle installing dependencies via the private registry with a `~/.pip/pip.conf` as such:

```
[global]
extra-index-url = https://****:****@company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple
trusted-host = company.jfrog.io
```

Now, when I try and `pip install internal_pkg`, all works just fine.  However, as I try to `pip install pandas` (for example), I get the following error:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://****:****@parkmobile.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple
Collecting pandas
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: Failed to parse: https://****:****@company.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi-local/simple/pandas/
```

Note, my username is my company email, hence has `@` and `.` symbols.

I am trying to understand why this is failing. How can I setup a `pip.conf` such that is looks first in my private registry, but looks at `pypi.org` for example if no package name is found on private.

Thanks!

Comment: will URL encoding like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39207316/pip-how-escape-character-in-password help?

Comment: @Mogi if you want to put answer i will mark it! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like explained here: [PIP how escape character # in password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39207316/pip-how-escape-character-in-password)

You can `URL encode` the 'problematic' character.
In your case `@` can be encoded into `%40`