# Pylint installation fails

Tags: python, installation, pylint

Using python 3.5.2, Windows 10

Via CMD (`python -m pip install pylint`), trying to install Pylint but connection times out, with following error:

```
Collecting pylint
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after 
connection broken by  
'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000024109748E56>, 'Connection to pypi.python.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/pylint/
```

What's the possible issue here? if anyone can suggest or have any views on this? Thanks!

Comment: you can download it and install it manually

Answer (score 0):

PyPI is served using a CDN, and since that was implemented the chances that PyPI is not available have been vastly reduced.

You check if you can reach https://pypi.python.org/pypi with your webbrowser, and if that doesn't work, check some other website, as this might be your own internetconnection.

If this happens often, you might want to consider setting up `devpi` (installed from PyPI) which can cache all request, so at least you can run your install (although you might get an update of a package with a little delay).

Answer (score 0):

Late answer,  but may help others that have a similar issue.  If you happened to be running the PIP command behind corporate firewall, you may get this same issue.  Search for "python pip proxy server" to see how you can specify a proxy server in the pip command.  Or you can download the wheel file (.whl) from PyPy and try installing it from there. This post may help.  The preferred method is one in which the username and password are not specified.

[How to get pip to work behind a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080352/how-to-get-pip-to-work-behind-a-proxy-server)