# pip install failing with 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: authentication, proxy, pip, rhel, tunnel

I am trying to use the below pip install command, but its failing with Proxy authentication required issue. I have already configured my proxies inside my RHEL7.x Server.

```
Command Used: `pip install --proxy https://'username:pwd'@proxy:host  --upgrade pip`
```

Logs:

```
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/pip/
```

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5144#issuecomment-394796676

Answer (score 19):

This is the first thing you should try:

Open the command prompt(CMD).

Export the proxy settings :

`:\set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyAddress:port`

`:\set https_proxy=https://username:password@proxyAddress:port`

Install the package you want to install:

`:\pip install PackageName`

Answer (score 6):

Error `407` means that the authentication for the proxy is missing / wrong. Remove the `'` from the `username:pwd` part, i.e. use: `pip install --proxy https://username:pwd@proxy:host`.

Try opening an internet connection from that server just prior to installing the Python package, as another option.

If this is not helping, try the the options given in the answers to the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9698557/5276734), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19080352/5276734) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14149422/5276734).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17884246)

Comment: You are right, I adapted my answer to be more than just a link.

Comment: No you need to encode special chars in your password . 
Follow below steps..
1) Open chrome dev tools and go to console.. 
2) Type encodeURIComponent('domain\\<username>:<password>')
3) It will return you encoded string.. Just copy paste it. @Oshada

Comment: @Oshada... Yes it'll detect and it'll work if your password contains an @. I have tried it and it worked.  No need to encode as said above

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal then execute:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxyAddress:port
export https_proxy=https://username:password@proxyAddress:port
```

I try this in git bash, in Windows.
I did not find a better answer with no password in a environment variable.

You could save this code, creating a ".bashrc" file in your home directory.

Comment: protocol shouldn't be in the value

Comment: Does it work without the protocol? It's good to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this is a way of manually installing pip if you have a problem with pip:

go to:
https://pypi.org/project/pip/#files
and download the pip file
when its downloaded extract it and navigate to:
\pip-23.2.1\src
you will find pip folder, copy it to: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages
and replace the old pip folder with the new one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There's authentication problem while connecting to proxy which causes 407 proxy issue.

Execute following commands to set proxy for your system.

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=https://User_Name:Password@proxy_address:Port
set https_proxy=https://User_Name:Password@proxy_address:Port

set HTTP_PROXY=http://User_Name:Password@proxy_address:Port
set http_proxy=http://User_Name:Password@proxy_address:Port
```

**Note: Check your environment environment variable has HTTP_PROXY/ HTTPS_PROXY variable set. If Yes, verify if those are set to correct values.**

As these values overwrite your current values.

Comment: what is `Proxy)Url"?