# I cant install any packages through pip it shows me error

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I cant install any packages through pip it shows me error:-

PS

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> pip install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0423C5D0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/virtualenv/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0423C3B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/virtualenv/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0423C290>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/virtualenv/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0423C090>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/virtualenv/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0423C7F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))': /simple/virtualenv/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for virtualenv
```

Comment: At first: it's kind of brave to use that folder as your working directory. Despite of that you should check if your proxy is properly configured and working. You should also try without any proxy settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install failing with 407 Proxy Authentication Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466241/pip-install-failing-with-407-proxy-authentication-required)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ProxyError+Cannot+connect+to+proxy

Answer (score 0):

This type of Error occurs while updating the pip.
But can be resolved by using following commands.

- step 1:

  `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`
- step 2:

  `python3 get-pip.p --force-reinstall`
- step 3:

Now check the pip version:

```
pip3 --version
```

Answer (score -1):

This can happen with older versions of `pip`. Try to upgrade it with `pip install --upgrade pip`