# Can't install packages for Python (3.11.4) (working through proxy server on windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, pip, proxy

Trying to install packages via PIP (in command line and VS code)

`pip install aiogram`

An error of the following type is output

`WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required'))': /simple/aiogram/ ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aiogram (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for aiogram`

The proxy in the `pip.ini` file is written in the format `proxy=http://user:pass@proxyserver:8080/`

doesn't help(

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46466241/pip-install-failing-with-407-proxy-authentication-required

Comment: it works like this 
`pip install aiogram --proxy http://user:pass@proxyserver:8080/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works like this `pip install aiogram --proxy http://user:pass@proxyserver:8080/`