# Create and use a PyPi proxy repository on nexus

Tags: python, pip

Running Nexus 3 OSS 3.6.0-02 I have created a pypi proxy repository on nexus using this guide:

https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/pypi-repositories

With the following info:

```
Format: pypi
Type: proxy
URL: https://mynexus:9666/nexus/pypi-proxy/
Remote Storage:https://pypi.org/
Authentication: Username/Password
```

Now I would like to install a package and use the above proxy. Based on:

[How to get pip to work behind a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080352/how-to-get-pip-to-work-behind-a-proxy-server/23103309)

and this example:

```
pip install --proxy http://user:password@proxyserver:port <package>
```

I have tried:

```
pip install --proxy https://myuser:mypassword@mynexus:9666/nexus/pypi-proxy/ testinfra --no-cache-dir
```

But I get:

```
Collecting testinfra
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Invalid response from tunnel request',))': /simple/testinfra/
```

Is there and error in my command line? Or something I need to configure on the server/repository?

Comment: curious how you created a pypi proxy. i am using nexus:oss on docker hub and the only options i get are maven1/2, nuget, npm, and gems

Answer (score 14):

Just add /simple at the end of index URL

`pip install --index-url https://myuser:mypassword@mynexus:9666/nexus/pypi-proxy/simple/`

Comment: This works. Can anyone explain why ?

Answer (score 6):

```sh
export PYPI_USER=<Username>
export PYPI_PASSWD=<Password>
export PYPI_HOST=mynexus:9666/nexus/pypi-proxy/simple/

pip config --global set global.index-url https://$PYPI_USER:$PYPI_PASSWD@$PYPI_HOST
pip config --global set global.trusted-host $PYPI_HOST

pip install testinfra
```

Comment: Don't ever use basic auth with http as it is insecure. Use https instead

Answer (score 0):

try

`pip install --index-url http://user:password@proxyserver:port <package>`

per https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/