# How to install PIP packages through a proxy?

Tags: python, pip

I have RHEL 8 server which has not internet connection and the server has a jupyter notebook installed. I need to install exchangelib module there. Since the server has no any internet connection I couldn't do that. So I started to create a proxy like below.

```
http_proxy  = "http://10.11.111.11:3128"
https_proxy = "https://10.11.111.11:3128"
ftp_proxy   = "ftp://10.11.111.11:3128"

proxyDict = { 
              "http"  : http_proxy, 
              "https" : https_proxy, 
              "ftp"   : ftp_proxy
            }

# setting up the URL and checking the connection by printing the status

url = 'https://www.google.lk'
page = requests.get(url, proxies=proxyDict)
print(page.status_code)
print(page.url)
```

The output of the following code is as follows.

```
200
https://www.google.lk
```

So I was able to connect to internet by using that. But I couldn't figure out how I install pip packages after that. Can anyone guide me on that?

Comment: Are you trying to use `pip` module in your own python code, or are you using command-line `pip` executable?

Comment: @alani  I have used pip Install exchangelib code at the begining of the script.But there was an error called module not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use [pip as a library](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program). pip project recommends using it with subprocess call.

```
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'my_package'])
```

Then for proxy you can add the `--proxy` flag to it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20818379/376535) Stackoverflow answer shows it well. But to complete the answer, this is how it should look like,

```
subprocess.check_call([
    sys.executable, 
    '-m',
    'pip',
    'install',
    '--proxy',
    'http://10.11.111.11:3128',
    'my_package'
])
```

Comment: This gives me an output as 0.What does it mean?

Comment: 0 is the exit code of the command you executed. 0 means its successful. non-zero is failure.