# I tried to install packages using pip but i got this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip, cython

[image]

> WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))': /simple/numpy/
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy

I tried to install packages using pip but i got this error. i've been breaking my head since a week.
can someone tell me what the error is? and how to resolve it

Answer (score 1):

That is an issue with your connection to PyPI, the Python package repository; the connection between your machine and PyPI servers gets aborted.

If you're in a corporate environment, you may need to tell `pip` to [use your corporate HTTP(S) proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19080352/how-to-get-pip-to-work-behind-a-proxy-server).

On the other hand, you may also already have a proxy (mis)configured, and it's that proxy that's aborting the connection.