# Downloading Python package with proxy settings

Tags: python-3.x

I am in my company office and I am not able to download any package in python till I am in their network. I am using python 3.6 and windows 8 (64 bit).
Is there any way to download package by setting or applying some proxy settings.. How to see my network internet proxy settings through  internet explorer?

I have checked the setting and its ticked in "Automatic Detect Settings"

I am getting this error:

```
pip install package_name

Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) 
after connection broken by 
'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.conne
ction.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000008C004E0EB8>: Failed to 
establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed',)
': /simple/gensim/
```

Comment: have you seen this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726881/how-to-set-an-http-proxy-in-python-2-7

Comment: set http_proxy=http://proxy.myproxy.com
set https_proxy=https://proxy.myproxy.com . How should I know what to use in both this http_proxy and https_proxy

Comment: they are likely both the same.