# why my code can not load MNIST dataset from google?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tensorflow

i need some your help

i can't load MNIST dataset from [this.](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz)

My system enviroment is as follows
OS : Ubuntu 16.04
Python version : 3.5
Tensorflow version : 1.12

Following is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

train, test = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
train_x, train_y = train

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(({"image":train_x}, train_y))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(100000).repeat().batch(10)

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

sess = tf.Session()

print(sess.run(next_element))
```

when i run this code on my computer it stucks at ETA0 and doesn't finishing downloading from google like this.

Downloading data from [here.](https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz)
11476992/11490434 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s

What should i do on this problem, please help me... :(

Comment: Try downloading the data manually, then pass the path like this [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data)

Comment: Please, check this directory for any datasets `~/.keras`

Comment: @Anwarvic Hey! it works! thanks bro! i downloaded dataset and place it to `~/.keras/datasets` manually and it works! thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Running fine on my Linux machine with Python3, must be a network issue.
Try changing the internet connection or check for proxies if any and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You may be behind a proxy... for example if you are on a corporate network.

On Windows the Python interpreter will get a proxy from your system environmental variables:

set the system variable HTTP_PROXY
to the value `http://yourproxy`

and the system variable HTTPS_PROXY
to the value `http://yourproxy`

Alternately, you can set the environment in a specific Python terminal session according to the answer to this post
[set proxy in python session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726881/how-to-set-an-http-proxy-in-python-2-7)