# Python: Pass every request over proxy

Tags: python, proxy, request

I'm currently trying to interact with the atlassian api via python: https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api.

My problem is, that my application runs in a network, where every connection must be passed over an internal proxy.
From questions like this: [How to pass all Python's traffics through a http proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639742/how-to-pass-all-pythons-traffics-through-a-http-proxy) I got to know how to configure the proxy on a Linux system.

In my case all systems are based on windows. Therefore I wanted to know if there are also ways to pass every request over the proxy on windows.

The question above also mentioned solutions on windows, but for me these solutions didn t look very trust worthy to run them in a internal network.

Are there other ways to pass every request over a proxy on a windows system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set an HTTP proxy in Python 2.7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726881/how-to-set-an-http-proxy-in-python-2-7)

Comment: @KlausD. if I correctly understood the answer from your link: The user needs to configure the http_proxy in the command line tool. In my case I want to have the script configure the proxy automatically because other people should use the software and they dont want to configure it themself.

Comment: Addition: The other people want to use the software on their devices.